# [ROS2] Python launch documentation

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there comprehensive documentation regarding ROS2's Python-based launch system?

I found examples and many questions/replies here, but I cannot find complete documentation reporting all the available data structures, their parameters, and their usage.

Sometimes is really not easy to understand how to perform a task that may be really simple.

Thank you,

Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382672/%5Bros2%5D-python-launch-documentation/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2021-07-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2021-07-17**:
No. There are very spare informations about that and some tutorials are completerly wrong, because no more updated since long time. At the end I finish looking
into the github code itself trying to understand, how the code works

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2021-07-17**:
That's exactly what I'm doing... but something it's easy to miss something better than what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation of ROS 2 should be improved. This [cookbook](https://github.com/mikeferguson/ros2_cookbook/blob/main/pages/launch.md) could help with some points. I'm also making this [project](https://github.com/pxalcantara/ros2_ex) to study, maybe you could find some useful examples of launch files

---

Originally posted by [Pedro Alcantara](https://answers.ros.org/users/25284/pedro-alcantara/) with karma: 56 on 2021-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2021-07-18**:
Thank you